# Why can't I change the background color of the navBar div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of the navBar div to black but it doesn't do anything when I try and set it. The reset.css is added at the bottom of the css snippet. I have tried many things to fix it and im not sure what causes it. If you could explain why it is not working in your answer that would be great.

```css
#navBar {
  background-color: black;
}

#liL {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}

.liR {
  float: right;
  margin: 60px 50px 0 0;
}

.linkNav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#logo {
  height: 100px;
}


/* CSS reset */

body,
div,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
fieldset,
input,
textarea,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

fieldset,
img {
  border: 0;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  padding: 3px 5px 4px;
  color: #979797;
  width: 190px;
}

address,
caption,
cite,
code,
dfn,
th,
var {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

caption,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
}

abbr,
acronym {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navBar">
    <ul id="ulNav">
      <li id="liL"><img id="logo" src="#"></li>
      <li class="liR"><a class="linkNav" href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="liR"><a class="linkNav" href="#">Locations</a></li>
      <li class="liR"><a class="linkNav" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="liR"><a class="linkNav" href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It has a height of 0px. `float` removes elements from the normal document flow so the height of the child doesn't make the parent element larger. I would recommend using Flexbox instead of float nowadays. CSS Tricks has a great reference for Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using floats you need to give the `ul` element some height.
One way to achieve this is to use the `overflow` property.

This makes sure the `ul` grows vertically to include its children:

```
#ulNav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But as already mentioned, it's best to use an alternative method, like flexbox, because floats were never meant for building layouts and can be elegantly substituted with the modern flex/grid.